# UX principles for maximizing web page visibility at a distance?

Tags: accessibility, contrast, design-principles, visibility, displays

This post is about maximizing visual clarity of a page, **not** SEO.

Some info about my project:

- The page will be displayed on a 1080p 42" television.
- Users will be standing 3 - 6 feet from the TV.
- The page holds six calendars, displaying reservation times for six rooms. This layout is a client request -- assume it can't be changed.

My first thought was to make the page high-contrast using extreme grayscale colors (see image below) but my client finds the current design too harsh and would like some color added.

I have searched for high-visibility design principles with little success. All advice welcome.

[image: Current grayscale design]

Comment: Welcome! This question is a bit broad and is veering into a design review type question, both of which are not on topic here. Can you focus the question on something more specific that would be relevant beyond your specific use case?

Comment: I'd suggest a variety of things: go with a dark background, lose the chart junk, bold type, bigger type, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminology commonly used for TV display's is the "10-foot" Graphical User Interface (GUI)

Some colour guidance in

- http://www.cmsbuffet.com/Designing-For-TV.php
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418274(v=vs.85).aspx

Notable highest contrast using solid white may not be best approach. Reds & oranges can be problematic.